# Always get newest prerelease package with NuGet

Tags: nuget, versioning

I have a project which consumes a prerelease package that is built on the CI system. As a developer, I always want to get the newest version when I do a NuGet restore.

Example:

Package built on the CI server and gets the version 1.0.0.1-prerelease where the last digit is the SVN revision.

I do a NuGet restore. I want to get 1.0.0.1-prerelease installed.

Then, the version 1.0.0.2-prerelease is built and published.

When I do a clean checkout and nuget restore again, the new version 1.0.0.2-prerelease should be installed

What should I write into the version field of the dependency in my packages.config file?

Best regards